# Restoring SQL files

Tags: sql, sql-server, restore, job-scheduling

I have recently purchased a website and have a good knowledge on MS SQL. I am currently in the process of restoring the database to the new dedicated server.

This has gone successfully so far and is working as intended, until I ran into two files that I do not know how to restore.

Files are TennantCleanUp.sql and UploadJob.sql.

I have asked the creator of these files what they are and how to restore them. In terms of how to restore them there was no advice back from him (think he is hinting that its my problem now).

He did provide the following description tho (which i think will help with the advice i need)

"
The TenantClean file is a job that runs periodically every 15 minutes.

The purpose for this job is that if a potential Tenant goes through the Letting process and does not fully complete the transaction, it temporarily holds the property in a state where nobody else can let it, and other users are shown a message stating its in the process of letting but could possibly go back into the list.

For example, if I was going through the process adding the tenant info at the same time as somebody else, there would be a chance of two tenants letting the same property, whereas this way the first person to start the process gets 15 minutes grace in order to finish it before it will allow anybody else."

Can anybody help me with what to do next to get these "jobs" working in MS SQL 2012.

JOB CODE

```
USE [msdb]
GO

/****** Object:  Job [TenantClean]    Script Date: 26/06/2014 11:07:33 ******/
BEGIN TRANSACTION
DECLARE @ReturnCode INT
SELECT @ReturnCode = 0
/****** Object:  JobCategory [Database Maintenance]    Script Date: 26/06/2014 11:07:34 ******/
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM msdb.dbo.syscategories WHERE name=N'Database Maintenance' AND category_class=1)
BEGIN
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_category @class=N'JOB', @type=N'LOCAL', @name=N'Database Maintenance'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback

END

DECLARE @jobId BINARY(16)
EXEC @ReturnCode =  msdb.dbo.sp_add_job @job_name=N'TenantClean', 
        @enabled=1, 
        @notify_level_eventlog=0, 
        @notify_level_email=0, 
        @notify_level_netsend=0, 
        @notify_level_page=0, 
        @delete_level=0, 
        @description=N'removes tenant info from a property that hasn''t been paid for.', 
        @category_name=N'Database Maintenance', 
        @owner_login_name=N'Chris', @job_id = @jobId OUTPUT
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
/****** Object:  Step [Remove tenant info older that 15mins]    Script Date: 26/06/2014 11:07:34 ******/
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId, @step_name=N'Remove tenant info older that 15mins', 
        @step_id=1, 
        @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
        @on_success_action=1, 
        @on_success_step_id=0, 
        @on_fail_action=2, 
        @on_fail_step_id=0, 
        @retry_attempts=3, 
        @retry_interval=1, 
        @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'TSQL', 
        @command=N'DELETE FROM PropertyTenant
WHERE   PaymentSuccessful = 0
AND DATEDIFF(minute, CreatedDate, GETDATE()) > 15', 
        @database_name=N'compRent', 
        @flags=0
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_update_job @job_id = @jobId, @start_step_id = 1
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobschedule @job_id=@jobId, @name=N'15minTenantClean', 
        @enabled=1, 
        @freq_type=4, 
        @freq_interval=1, 
        @freq_subday_type=4, 
        @freq_subday_interval=15, 
        @freq_relative_interval=0, 
        @freq_recurrence_factor=0, 
        @active_start_date=20130617, 
        @active_end_date=99991231, 
        @active_start_time=0, 
        @active_end_time=235959, 
        @schedule_uid=N'4749c1e7-a8a9-4482-9d52-22e95a4f7686'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver @job_id = @jobId, @server_name = N'(local)'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
COMMIT TRANSACTION
GOTO EndSave
QuitWithRollback:
    IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
EndSave:

GO
```

Thanks

Comment: You should look into setting up a job schedule using the agent in SQL Server. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439.aspx

Comment: I looked at this and even watched a video but my SQL server didn't seem to have this agent in the tree. Also is it possible to just restore them or would i need to rewrite them

Comment: You don't "restore" .sql files, you execute them, simply paste them into the management studio application, in a query window linked to your database server, and execute the scripts. Granted, the scheduled script you will need to find that agent for, but the other script should (probably) just be executed. However, since you don't tell us what these scripts do, it's impossible to actually give you an answer here.

Comment: I question your claim that you have good knowledge of MS SQL though, and don't know what a .sql file is. Have you opened them up in a text editor and looked at them?

Comment: Well thanks am looking into SQL server agent now. i had a good basic knowledge as in I can code stored procedures and such and create databases and access them from my asp.net website.... I just have never user server agent.

Comment: turns out express does not have server agent and this is my problem... just need a work around now

Comment: Then you need to use the windows scheduler to do this, just google for examples on how to set this up.

Comment: I found this and am using "sqlcmd -S T800-907 -E -d msdb -i TenantClean.sql" but get this error "Changed database context to 'msdb'.
Msg 14261, Level 16, State 1, Server T800-907, Procedure sp_verify_job, Line 57
The specified @name ('TenantClean') already exists."

Comment: So TenantClean is adding a procedure or something similar, did you open up the files in a text editor to verify what they're actually doing?

Comment: Am not to sure what its doing to be honest but am now using this sqlcmd -S T800-907 -E -d msdb -Q "execute msdb.dbo.sp_startjob @job_name = 'TenantClean'" and get error C:\Websites\Let-RentJobs>sqlcmd -S T800-907 -E -d msdb -Q "execute msdb.dbo.sp_s
tartjob job_name = 'TenantClean'"
Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Server T800-907, Line 1
Could not find stored procedure 'msdb.dbo.sp_startjob'." ill add the script above

Comment: Iv added the job script to the main question above.... BTW thanks for this continued help i am thankful :)

Answer (score 0):

Incase anyone was wondering i figured this out.

To make this work without SQL Agent, you must go into the SQL file and extract the command....

In my case it was

```
 @command=N'DELETE FROM PropertyTenant
WHERE   PaymentSuccessful = 0
AND DATEDIFF(minute, CreatedDate, GETDATE()) > 15',
```

so i used copied

```
'DELETE FROM PropertyTenant
WHERE   PaymentSuccessful = 0
AND DATEDIFF(minute, CreatedDate, GETDATE()) > 15'
```

and pasted it a notepad file.

```
sqlcmd -S COMPUTERNAME -E -d DATABASENAME -Q "COMMAND HERE" >> OUTPUTFILENAME.txt 2>&1
```

And replaced it with the following

```
sqlcmd -S T800-907 -E -d TenantDB -Q "DELETE FROM PropertyTenant WHERE PaymentSuccessful = 0 AND DATEDIFF(minute, CreatedDate, GETDATE()) > 15" >> TenantCleanLog.txt 2>&1
```

I then saved this as a .bat file. When the bat file is run it will save the output to tenantCleanLog.txt.

Also this can be schedualed to run from windows task schedualar.

Hope this helps anyone in my shoes :D

I then found this code on the internet